resurrectable individual zsh history for tmux panes
I heavily rely on tmux sessions to manage workspaces for varying use-cases.
my .tmux.conf utilizes tmux-resurrect and tmux-continuum to backup my environment at a 1 minute interval and persist across reboots / crashes.
I have been trying to implement individual, pane-specific history files that would allow zsh panes to have their own isolated history.
the following function that is auto-run in my .zshrc exports the $HISTFILE parameter expectdly (during both pane creation and restoration):
update_histfile () {
         if [[ -n $TMUX ]]; then
                 mkdir -p $HOME/.zsh_history.d

                 TMUX_SESSION_NAME=$(tmux display-message -p "#{session_name}")
                 TMUX_WINDOW_NAME=$(tmux display-message -p "#{window_name}")
                 TMUX_PANE_INDEX=$(tmux display-message -p "#{pane_index}")
    
                 export HISTFILE="$HOME/.zsh_history.d/${TMUX_SESSION_NAME}_${TMUX_WINDOW_NAME}_${TMUX_PANE_INDEX}.hist"
         else
                 export HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history
         fi
}

However, running the history command in a newly restored pane reveals that its output differs from the contents of the correctly assigned $HISTFILE. This is likely due to the behavior of tmux-resurrect's pane restoration process, as all panes' histories are that of a random pane.
Running fc -p $HISTFILE in the restored pane fixes the issue as history and cat $HISTFILE are a match afterwards.
I've tried appending the fc command to the end of my .zshrc but that was of no help.
For example, after restoring the environment using tmux-resurrect and switching to a pane where I only ran the commands cat $HISTFILE and fc -p $HISTFILE, I can notice that when using the arrow keys to cycle through previously run commands, some commands from a different pane show up.
notice the mismatch between the commands that are returned by history and the actual contents of the correctly assigned $HISTFILE:
┌───(biscuit@a)──[~/.tmux/plugins/tmux-resurrect/scripts]
└─$ history
    1  nvim /home/biscuit/.zshrc
    2  whoami
    3  echo $HISTFILE
    4  nvim /home/biscuit/.zshrc
    5  history
    6  cat $HISTFILE
    7  hist
    8  nvim ~/.tmux.conf
    9  history
   10  clear
   11  cd ~/.tmux/plugins/tmux-resurrect
   12  ls -la
   13  nvim resurrect.tmux
   14  nvim restore.sh
   15* nvim /home/biscuit/.zshrc
   16* nvim /home/biscuit/.tmux.conf
   17* nvim restore.sh

┌───(biscuit@a)──[~/.tmux/plugins/tmux-resurrect/scripts]
└─$ cat $HISTFILE
: 1733038763:0;whoami
: 1733042390:0;cat $HISTFILE

after running fc -p in the pane, the issue is resolved:
┌───(biscuit@a)──[~/.tmux/plugins/tmux-resurrect/scripts]
└─$ fc -p $HISTFILE

┌───(biscuit@a)──[~/.tmux/plugins/tmux-resurrect/scripts]
└─$ history
    1  whoami
    2  cat $HISTFILE
    3  fc -p $HISTFILE


Just to clarify, is $HISTFILE set correctly for each pane by the end of your .zshrc, or do you need to run update_histfile again after startup? Also, what history-related options do you have enabled (setopt | grep hist)?
